# Почему после выполнения функции переменная обьекта очищается?

Tags: python, классы

Вот сам код

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-s


class Player():
    heals = 100
    manna = 0

    def __init__(self, heals, manna):
        self.manna = manna
        self.heals = heals

def set():
    act = int(input("Выберите класс:\n1)Воин\n2)Маг\n3)Палладин:"))
    if act == 1:
        pl1 = Player(10, 100)
    elif act == 2:
        pl1 = Player(25, 100)
    elif act == 3:
        pl1 = Player(50, 50)
    else:
        print("Не верное значение")
        set()

    print(pl1.manna)
    return pl1.manna, pl1.heals

set()
print(pl1.manna)
```

Ошибка

```sh
Выберите класс:
1)Воин
2)Маг
3)Палладин:1
100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(pl1.manna)
NameError: name 'pl1' is not defined
mi@ubuntu:~/Рабочий стол$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `pl1` находится в пределах области видимости функции `set`
Это означает, что за пределами функции её не существует как таковой
Чтобы воспользоваться результатом, который вы передаёте, нужно его сохранять в переменную:

```py
class Player():
    # базовые значения лучше объявлять так - это избавляет от необходимости указывать конструктор по умолчанию. Если параметры указаны - они будут использоваться. Нет - будут вызваны параметры по умолчанию
    def __init__(self, heals = 100, manna = 0):
        self.manna = manna
        self.heals = heals

def set():
    act = int(input("Выберите класс:\n1)Воин\n2)Маг\n3)Палладин:"))
    if act == 1:
        pl1 = Player(10, 100)
    elif act == 2:
        pl1 = Player(25, 100)
    elif act == 3:
        pl1 = Player(50, 50)
    else:
        print("Не верное значение")
        set()

    print(pl1.manna)
    return pl1.manna, pl1.heals

player1 = set()   # сюда помещается кортеж (manna, heals)
print(player1[0]) # вывести manna
print(player1[1]) # вывести heals
```

Хотелось бы дополнить, что использовать `set` в качестве названия функции - плохое решение, поскольку существует стандартный тип данных `set` в языке Python. Занимать зарезервированные имена для своих нужд - не очень хорошая привычка. Советую от неё избавляться

Т.к. вы возвращаете скалярные значения, а не объект, теряется всякий смысл использования классов как таковых. Лучше функцию `set` объявить таким образом:

```py
def set():
    act = int(input("Выберите класс:\n1)Воин\n2)Маг\n3)Палладин:"))
    if act == 1:
        pl1 = Player(10, 100)
    elif act == 2:
        pl1 = Player(25, 100)
    elif act == 3:
        pl1 = Player(50, 50)
    else:
        print("Не верное значение")
        set()

    print(pl1.manna)
    return pl1
```

Тогда дальнейшая работа с объектом выглядит так:

```py
player1 = set()
print(player1.manna)
print(player1.heals)
player1.manna = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо результат выполнения функции присвоить переменной и её уже отображать.

Пример:

```py
class Player():
    heals = 100
    manna = 0

    def __init__(self, heals, manna):
        self.manna = manna
        self.heals = heals

def set():
    act = int(input("Выберите класс:\n1)Воин\n2)Маг\n3)Палладин:"))
    if act == 1:
        pl1 = Player(10, 100)
    elif act == 2:
        pl1 = Player(25, 100)
    elif act == 3:
        pl1 = Player(50, 50)
    else:
        print("Не верное значение")
        set()

    print(pl1.manna)
    return pl1.manna, pl1.heals

a = set()
print(a)
```